Electric motor running in reverse
I purchased a machine from China and they must have wired up the motor wrong because the pulley wheel is running counterclockwise when I need to it to run clockwise to properly work the machine. I’ve done a little research on Google but want to make sure I get this right and don’t fry the motor so I took some pics and would appreciate anyone who knows for sure what I need to do to change the direction telling me what I need to do.


As you can see in the pics there is a blue and white capacitor, the blue one is noticeably larger than the white although I can’t see the numbers on either id have to pull them out and they appear to be anchored in with some sort of adhesive foam.
Both capacitors have a blue and brown wire.
Across the top row the terminals (if that’s the correct term) are labeled from left to right V2 U2 Z2
The bottom row from left to right are Z1 V1 U1
The blue wire from both capacitors is hooked to Z1.
The brown wire from the white smaller capacitor is hooked to V1 and the brown wire from the larger blue capacitor is hooked to v2.
I read something about “switching the Z connections” but I wasn’t sure if that meant to switch one of the blue wires to Z2 or both of them or if that was wrong completely.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

where does the supply connect?

I’ll have to look again when I go back to the shop to be sure but I believe the brown is to U2 and yellow and blue to U1. Some pics have been added if that helps.

Did you connect PE to one of the motor windings? It looks like that in the pictures!

I didn’t connect anything, this is the way it came, all I’ve done is remove the back plate

It looks to me like Z1 & Z2 connect to the auxiliary winding in the motor. This winding gets connected in series with one or both capacitors (both at startup, one while running) and it's the polarity of this winding which determines what direction the motor turns.
Unlike a 3-phase motor, a single-phase motor needs those capacitors to create a phase-shift in the current flowing through the auxiliary winding, and (simplistically) the resulting phase-shifted magnetic field is what gets the motor turning.
So you need to rewire it so that instead of:
V2 U2 Z2
Z1 V1 U1
you have
V2 U2 Z1
Z2 V1 U1
You'll need to remove the 2 blue capacitor wires from the current Z2 in the bottom left corner, but after you put Z1 in that position both of those blue wires to back in the same place.
Similarly once Z1 is up in the top-right corner, the link from there down to U1 goes back on the same way it is now.

Ok thanks. So I need to swap the locations rear black wires with the letters/numbers z1 and z2 and put everything back the way it is? Can I ask, would simply switching the blue wires to the z2 where it is now not work? I’m assuming because they shouldn’t be connected to U1? Is there any other info or pics I can provide for you to be more sure of this or are you already 100%? Not questioning your knowledge at all, I’m just completely ignorant of this stuff and really can’t afford to fry this motor so if there’s anything else I can try to provide let me know, if not I’ll move forward with this

Fun what I can see in your pics I'm 99.9% certain that what I've described will work to reverse the direction of rotation. Moving the 2 blue wires from the capacitors over would not have the desired effect. If you did that the motor would probably but run at all, and one or both capacitors might start to head up.

Ok thanks, I will try it tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Is it common for the Chinese to use euro color wiring?

@GideonHawk the diagrams in archaido's answer are a mirror-image of what you have on your motor (top-row Z2-U2-V2 instead of your V2-U2-Z2, bottom U1-V1-Z1 instead of your Z1-V1-U1), and Hot/Live and Neutral are also reversed - but the underlying principal is the same. In that diagram is looks like swapping the position of the jumpers reverses the polarity on the main winding but leaves the aux/capacitor winding the same - this has the same end result as what I proposed, but would probably be easier to do.

@brahns I see now what his answer. Although the order isn’t the same in his video, the actual connections based on the black wire labeling and the jumpers are identical to what I have in the “forward” imagine in the video. So basically I need to change around the jumpers, not the wires. One thing though, my motor is moving “reverse” as it is (counterclockwise) even through the wiring matches the “forward” so I’ll be switching it to “reverse” in the diagram to actually achieve forward, any issues with this? Thanks again.

@brahns I went ahead and did it your original suggestion. It took a little more work but now it’s running correctly. Thanks so much

Labels U,V and Z (not U. V and W) hints that the motor is a 2 phase induction motor which is designed to be run with single phase AC voltage; the needed phase shifted second AC voltage is generated by a capacitor.
Unfortunately the good capacitor is different for reliable starting and for running effectively at full speed. The motor has inbuilt centrifugal  switch which changes the capacitance smaller (=disconnects the 2nd capacitor) when there's high enough r.p.m. The next image is taken from a YouTube guidance video:

The video is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiZgXq11lHQ
I would try this. But find at first the right terminals where the motor windings and the switch are really connected to in the motor. I cannot exactly see what is stamped to the plastic connector block behind the wires and nothing guarantees the stamps are valid for the actual connection. The idea is to swap the ends of ONE of the windings.
Here's an easy to read technical discussion of single phase induction AC motors https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-13/single-phase-induction-motors/ It has no connector labels like U, V, Z because the theory doesn't need them and they can be whatever either by a factory who doesn't respect western standards or the connections are changed by a thoughtless person who was happy when he happened to get his motor running.
Hopefully the inbuilt capacitor switch and motor cooling works equally to both rotating directions. Anything which is based on air pressure can suffer if it's not designed for both directions.

Neither of your forward or reverse diagrams seem to match the image provided by the OP...

@SolarMike For that reason I suggested to find the actual ends of the windings and the switch. I added to the answer a little about it.

Ok thanks. How do I know what terminals are really connected? Are you saying that the labeling on the black wires could be incorrect or are they they true wiring and the stamps on the plastic could be incorrect? I’ll have to look but I think the stamps on the plastic were different order than the yellow labels on the black wires, so which do I go by. I’m also not sure exactly what the video is saying I need to do in terms of which wires need to be moved and to where.

The connections can be now anything. It may be a version which makes it run somehow, Why I suspect it's not the perfect one? Because in the photo yellow-green wire seems to be connected to the same screw than something inside the motor. If you cannot disassemble this to find where are the windings and do not see anything alarming in the place of the yellow green wire, stop immediately as long as you can decide it (no coffin is still needed). Let a qualified electrician clear the mess. We cannot measure anything of your system with our computers.

@archaido, I see now what it’s saying. Although the order isn’t the same in your video, the actual connections based on the black wire labeling and the jumpers are identical to what I have in the “forward” imagine in the video. So basically I need to change around the jumpers, not the wires. One thing though, my motor is moving “reverse” as it is (counterclockwise) even through the wiring matches the “forward” so I’ll be switching it to “reverse” in the diagram to actually achieve forward, any issues with this? Thanks again.

@archaido in the comments of the video someone points out that the main winding is actually reversed in their “forward” diagram, which explains why I’m getting counterclockwise rotation with that same layout. So I’m assuming the Z is the main winding? Are there any potential drawbacks to keeping it this way and simply switching the jumpers vs swapping the z1 and z2?

If you really swap the ends of exactly one winding it should work. The reversed winding can be as well the other one. In both cases the magnetic field rotation is reversed. I cannot comment moving jumpers or wires by labels before I have made measurements. As I said hopefully the motor is designed for both running directions (=still cooled, the switch works too). The yellow-green wire shouldn't be  connected to any circuit, its strictly reserved only for protective grounding of the metal shell of the motor. As long as I cannot see it's used properly I cannot agree the connections are right.

@GideonHawk Your photo has been taken in  poor yellowish light I guess. To see does it make one wire to look yellow-green I made this https://i.sstatic.net/0gsMFHCY.png The wire looks still yellow-green. Do you perhaps live in a country where theregulation code allows that color being used freely in installations which are connected to the mains AC?

@archaido that wire is yellow and it’s coming from the power cord that plugs into the wall. From my understanding it’s the ground wire. What should it be attached to?

I see there's also green stripes. Do I see wrong? The protective ground should be connected to the metal case of the motor. Line and neutral wires should be connected to the circuit. I recommend stopping immediately as long as you are alive and your house has not caught a fire. I'm sorry but I cannot see here if also your house has got something special by the person who uses yellow-green freely. Better to get a local qualified electrician to make the checks.

@archaido I’m headed to the shop now, will look to see what it’s actually connected to, yes there appears to be a green stripe

@archaido the yellow/green wire is connected to the housing wall not to the circuit, the angle of the pic just makes it look that way

OK. Then swap the ends of one winding. I cannot say what's written to the wires . Hopefully U1 and U2 or alternatively Z1 and Z2 and you find a way to do it by moving only the shorting stripes between the screws.

I swapped the z1 and z2 and it worked, machine is running good and in the correct direction now. Appreciate your help.

Leave the capacitors where they are and switch any two of the incoming power wire. This will change the rotation.

Ok thanks. Just to make sure I’m understanding correctly, I believe the brown supply line is hooked to u2 and blue to U1 and yellow to U1, I’m assuming you mean switch the blue to u2 and brown to U1 and leave the yellow where it is? Thanks again

I can not see from the picture buy I guess the three input wires are Z1, V1 and U1. So leave the capacitor wires where they are and switch the position of any two of the incoming terminal block.

Make sure you disconnect the motor from power and short the capacitors.

The brown is to U2 and both the blue and yellow are on U1, so can I just switch the blue and brown and leave the yellow? Is there any issue with the yellow being on the same one as another one? Thanks

Could you sent a better photo of the wiring block. Was there a connection diagram with the motor?

That's a single phase motor with a euro color coded cable. Hot/Live on brown, Neutral on Blue, Ground/Earth on Yellow/Green. Swapping Brown & Blue will make no difference. Swapping Yellow/Green with either of the others will lead to trouble.

I’ll have to take one at the shop tomorrow.

Brhans are you saying swapping the blue and brown won’t change the direction? Do you know what will?

@GideonHawk Go back and re-read the answer BRHans already gave you. Then read it again to make sure you follow it.
